# Which words in -us get their plural in -i?

Tags: latin, pluriel, emprunts

The only¹ plural form I know for *stimulus* is *stimuli*. Are there other words that still get a Latin plural form in French?

Thanks.

---

1 - except *autobi* that I have very seldom seen in Literature (*Exercices de style*, Raymond Queneau).

Comment: In French, unlike English, latin forms are readily localised and '-us' plurals tend to stay the same. Neutral forms ('-um') are *sometimes* used with their latin plurals (*maximum* => *maxima*), but not always. Note that modern English usage does frown on the overuse of latin plurals (and some people will justifiably stone you if you ever utter such horrors as "virii" or "ignorami").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je crois que l'usage le plus courant (même pour stimulus) est le pluriel en -us.  Par exemple, Grevisse (*le bon usage*, 12ième édition 1986) dit en général pour les pluriels de mots d'origine étrangère :

> Dans beaucoup de cas, on trouve les deux usages, et on peut considérer que les pluriels empruntés sont un luxe inutile et souvent une pédanterie.

et plus particulièrement pour les mots en -us :

> Quelques noms en -us reçoivent un pluriel en -i.
>
> [...] Au lieu des plur. *oculus*, *papyrus*, *stimulus*, *tumulus*, certains croient devoir employer un pluriel à base latine [quelques exemples]

Il constate (comme toujours) les usages divergents, mais sa préférence est claire.

English summary: keeping the plural in -us is a better bet than using the Latin one in -i.

Answer (score 10):

The straightforward plural formation (adding `-s`, except that words ending with `-s`, `-x` or `-z` are unchanged) is always correct for imported words. Some words, especially those imported from Latin, retain an imported plural on the side; different people tend to have different preferences. Only words that are fully integrated into French can have an irregular plural as the sole correct form.

Oh, and *autobi* is meant as a joke. Queneau uses a form that no one would think of as correct but everyone with enough culture would understand as a stylistic effect.

---

La formation normale du pluriel (ajout d'un `-s`, en laissant invariants les mots se terminant par `-s`, `-x` ou `-z`) est toujours correcte pour un mot importé. Certains mots, surtout des emprunts du latin, conservent également leur pluriel importé ; les préférences pour l'un ou l'autre varient suivant les gens. Seuls les mots pleinement intégrés en français peuvent avoir seulement un pluriel irrégulier.

La forme *autobi* est une forme plaisante. Queneau utilise une forme que personne ne considérerait comme correcte mais que tout le monde suffisamment cultivé comprend, c'est un effet de style.

---

Here are a few examples, with plurals ordered by [1800–2000 ngram frequency (most used first)](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/).
Voici quelques exemples, avec les pluriels ordonnés par [fréquence de ngrams pour 1800–2000 (avec le plus utilisé en premier)](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/).

Un stimulus, des *stimuli* ou *stimulus*.
Un cirrus, des *cirrus* ou *cirri*.
Un *maximum*, des *maxima* ou *maximums*.
Un *consortium*, des *consortiums* ou *consortia*.
Un *tempo*, des *tempi* ou *tempos*.
Un *spaghetti*, des *spaghettis* ou *spaghetti*.
Un *goy*, des *goyim* ou *goys*.
Un *leitmotiv*, des *leitmotive* ou des *leitmotiv* ou des *leitmotivs*.

Comment: Et moi qui croyais qu'on disais un spaghetto.

Comment: "forme plaisante" pour "joke"? C'en est une?

Comment: @Joubarc *Un spaghetto* est une forme pédante ou plaisante ultraminoritaire (encore plus que *des spaghetti* est minoritaire). « Forme plaisante » est une terminologie usuelle, désignant une forme volontairement surprenante ou incorrecte par effet de style ; [exemple au hasard](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/en%20deux%20temps%20trois%20mouvements).

Comment: merci, encore un truc que j'ignorais. j'ai bien fait de ne pas éditer :-) Maintenant, question inverse... si c'est un terme usuel, peut-être a-t-il une meilleure traduction en anglais?