# Pluriel des mots latins et des mots empruntés à d'autres langues

Tags: pluriel, latin, emprunts

Je suis toujours dans le doute quand je dois mettre un mot latin au pluriel en parlant français bien sûr. Par exemple on dit :

> un syllabus, des syllabi ou des syllabus ?
>
> un forum, des forums ou des forum ? (car apparemment forum serait invariable...)
>
> un Avé Maria, deux Avé Maria ou deux Avés Marias ?

Je suis dans le flou, existe-t-il des règles précises ?

Comment: je ne peux pas répondre pour les deux autres mais le pluriel de forum c'est fora.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which words in -us get their plural in -i?](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/441/which-words-in-us-get-their-plural-in-i)

Answer (score 6):

Sans parler de règles précises définies par l'Académie (que je ne connais pas), mais plutôt de règles d'usage, mettre au pluriel un mot latin avec autre chose qu'un 's' final fera souvent passer le locuteur pour quelqu'un de pédant, à l'oral en tout cas. Il est plus courant d'entendre "des forums", "des syllabus", etc.

Il en va de même pour les mots étrangers en général. Il m'a toujours paru prétentieux d'utiliser "un scenario / des scenarii", voire carrément ridicule de dire "un spaghetto / des spaghetti", au nom d'un prétendu respect de l'origine du mot.

Cependant, j'aurais tendance à trouver normal qu'une personne utilise le pluriel d'origine lorsque le mot fait partie de son jargon : un professionel du cinéma parlant de scenarii (poussant la chose jusqu'à omettre l'accent sur le 'e'), un météorologue évoquant des maxima saisonniers, etc.

Comment: Encore une fois, ça dépend. Autant "spaghetto" est franchement risible, autant "scenarii" ou "paparazzo" me semblent plus acceptés.

Comment: @ElenaMellor Je pense que j'aurais tendance à trouver normale l'utilisation de la forme "correcte" chez quelqu'un du milieu : un professionel du cinéma qui parlerait de scenarii, un météorologue évoquant des maxima saisonniers, ... Dans les autres cas, et c'est vraiment une impression personnelle, ça m'a toujours paru prout-prout :)

Comment: Dans le cadre précis de maximum/minimum, il me semble tout à fait naturel (et pas spécialement pédant) de dire "des maxima". Ce fut du moins l'usage dans tous mes cours de sciences. Signalons également qu'il est tout à fait possible de dire : un erratum, des errata. Mais effectivement, pour "un spaghetto" possède une teneur particulèrement ridicule

Comment: @HerbertQuain, "cours de science", on est bien dans le jargon plus que dans la langue courante (et le problème principal des jargons, c'est que ceux qui les pratiquent -- moi inclus -- oublient que ce sont des jargons et pas la koinè).

Comment: À côté du pédantisme, qui existe certainement, il y a aussi par exemple le bilinguisme. Prenons les inuits du Québec: certains parlent un excellent français, mais le français demeure tout de même une langue seconde pour eux. La plupart utilisent le couple singulier/pluriel _inuk/inuit_, contre les recommendations officielles. Les canadiens-français qui les côtoient régulièrement peuvent très bien prendre ce pli (pour diverses raisons: respect, exposition, ...) sans que le pédantisme y joue un rôle. Comme il y a plusieurs zones de contacts linguistiques dans la Francophonie...

Answer (score 5):

Pour les emprunts, on peut utiliser soit un pluriel suivant la règle générale du français (ajout d'un `s` final, sauf si le mot se termine par `s`, `x` ou `z` auquel cas il ne varie pas), soit en calquant le pluriel de la langue étrangère. Ainsi : *des maximums* ou *des maxima*, *des forums* ou *des fora*, *des syllabus* ou *des syllabi*, *des spaghettis* ou *des spaghetti*, *des leitmotivs* ou *des leitmotive*, *des kibboutz* ou *des kibboutzim*, etc.

Depuis la [réforme orthographique de 1990](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990#Les_modifications_apport.C3.A9es), le pluriel régulier français est le seul [officiellement recommandé](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/sites/academie-francaise.fr/files/rectifications_1990.pdf) :

> - mots empruntés : pour l’accentuation et le pluriel, les mots empruntés suivront les règles des mots français (exemple : un imprésario, des imprésarios) ;
>
> […]
>
> Ces propositions sont présentées sous forme, d’une part, de règles d’application générale et de modifications de graphies particulières, destinées aux usagers et à l’enseignement, et, d’autre part, sous forme de recommandations à l’usage des lexicographes et des créateurs de néologismes.

J'insiste que la validité du pluriel régulier n'est pas une nouveauté, seulement le fait de le recommander officiellement. Ainsi le très conservateur [Littré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littr%C3%A9) [précisait](http://www.littre.org/definition/maximum) :

> Les mathématiciens disent au pluriel des maxima ; mais les grammairiens demandent qu'on traite ce mot comme français, et qu'on dise des maximums.

De nos jours même les mathématiciens disent de plus en plus *maximums*.

Certains mots comportent des particularités. Ainsi *forum* a été considéré comme invariable (par [Littré notamment](http://www.littre.org/definition/forum)), peut-être parce qu'il a été vu comme un nom propre (nom de lieu) même si c'était bien un nom commun (comme *place* en français) — mais *fora* et *forums* sont [aussi attestés](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=les+forum%2Cles+forums%2Cles+fora&year_start=1800&year_end=1900&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cles%20forum%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20forums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cles%20fora%3B%2Cc0) (au 20<sup>e</sup> siècle, *forums* domine nettement). Pour *syllabus*, le pluriel *syllabi* est quasiment inusité ; là, c'est peut-être parce que ce mot est du latin tardif voire une erreur de transcription (voir l'étymologie dans le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/syllabus)).

Pour ce qui est de *Ave Maria*, c'est un nom propre — un texte désigné par ses premiers mots. Je n'ai jamais vu cette expression francisée en *Avé Maria*, ni portant une marque de pluriel. La réforme orthographique de 1990 préconise une accentuation à la française, mais cela ne s'applique qu'aux emprunts, pas aux noms propres. Une citation surtout a vocation à être invariable.

Comment: _Maxima_ & _minima_ sont bien en recul, mais ils n’ont pas encore tout à fait rendu leur dernier souffle. Une autre tendance forte se dessine, cependant: on parle désormais [plus de minimum que de maximum](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=maximums%2Cmaxima%2Cminimums%2Cminima&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmaximums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaxima%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminimums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cminima%3B%2Cc0)! Peut-être les dépenses sont-elles désormais plus importantes que la production?

Answer (score 2):

Pour les mots latins devenus français ("syllabus", "corpus" (dans le sens d'un corpus de texte), "agenda"...), les mots prennent un "s" à la fin ou restent tels quels comme dans le cas de "corpus", "syllabus". En revanche, l'usage est plus particulier pour le reste : certains emploient "fora" et d'autres "forums". Pour ce qui est de l'*Ave Maria*, il reste 1) sans accent, 2) sans "s" car c'est une locution latine. De même pour "a priori", dans les discussions récentes.

Answer (score 1):

Certains des mots empruntés à des langues étrangères (latin compris) ont été intégrés à la langue française.

Un très bon exemple est le mot [*scénario*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sc%C3%A9nario) qui est originaire de l'italien *scenario* (sing.) / *scenarii* (plur.).

Le mot fait désormais partie de la langue française : il s'écrit avec un accent aigu et prend pour pluriel *scénarios*.

Un second exemple serait le mot [*forum*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forum) qui est originaire du latin *forum* (sing.) / *fora* (plur.), et dont le pluriel français est *forums*.

---

Il sera laborieux de tous les lister, mais on peut en trouver bien d'autres.